# Creating a Gender field

Tags: java

I made following code for Gender field in a form and i can't find my error. Any help is appreciated

```
    Gender =  
 if (male.isSelected()) Gender="Male";
 else if(female.isSelected()) Gender="Female";
```

I am new to NetBeans and this Site. So Please Help Me

I get the error in if statement

Answer (score 4):

You should not initialize `String` with `if` instead use :

```
String gender = "";

if (male.isSelected()) {
    gender = "Male";
} else if (female.isSelected()) {
    gender = "Female";
}
```